# How to find density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, density-operator

The Beam-splitter matrix is $ B  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} $.

I want to apply $a^{\dagger}_{1}a^{\dagger}_{2} |00\rangle_{12}$ as the input state for beam-splitter  (two photon at two input ports).

How can i find density matrix for this state?

Density matrix of input state for one photon at one of two ports is(if my understanding is correct)
$$ \rho = |\Psi\rangle \langle\Psi| = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: If I understand well, here you find this same computation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect#Mathematical_description

Comment: this computation isn't using density matrix.